# Xpath get the text from the first instance in each pair of classes

Tags: php, dom, xpath

I use the following xpath query to get the text, but it grabs the text from both and I only need it from the first instance of price from each group there are several groups on a page so I am having trouble limiting it.

Is there a way to limit it so I am just getting the span with a single class?

`$prices = $xpath->query('//span[@class="a-price"]/span');`

```
<div>
    <span class="price">
        text.      <---This is the one I need
    <span>
    <span class="price red">
        text
    <span>
</div>

blah blah blah

<div>
    <span class="price">
        text.      <---This is the one I need
    <span>
    <span class="price red">
        text
    <span>
</div>

blah blah blah 

<div>
    <span class="price">
        text.      <---This is the one I need
    <span>
    <span class="price red">
        text
    <span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

With this particular html, if you change your xpath query to

```
//div//span[@class="price"][1]/text()
```

or

```
//div//span[@class="price"]/text()[1]
```

you should get your expected output.